# Unity: getting the forces of a collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

My current approach is this. oldVelocity is the velocity of trackObject(a rigidbody I'm tracking). The starting oldVelocity is derived at the start of the corutine that contains this code and it's just the trackObject's current velocity.magnitude.

```
float force;
float acceleration;
float mass;
     
mass = trackObject.mass;
acceleration = (trackObject.velocity.magnitude - oldVelocity);
oldVelocity = trackObject.velocity.magnitude;
     
force = mass * acceleration;
force = Mathf.Abs(force);
```

This code produces a graph that looks along the lines of a triangle with the peak being the collision even though I'm expecting a bell shaped curve. I'm also making sure to run this code on FixedUpdate for more accurate physics read-outs from Unity.

Image of the graph

[image]

I'm attempting to graph the force curve of a collision in Unity. Not the impulse which is given by [this Collision field](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-impulse.html).

I'm also not looking for the sum of the forces but just the force at every frame during the collision.

Any feedback and suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at the [relative velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-relativeVelocity.html)? Also beware that you are not likely to get a Bell curve. Unity physics are only an approximation of what happens when rigidbodies collide with eachother, it's not like you'd get an accurate buildup of forces as the collisions are likely to be resolved after one 'physics frame'